# Yeoman/Grunt and Grunticon workflow

Tags: javascript, svg, gruntjs, yeoman

I've started working with Yeoman. I was already using GruntIcon. I'm trying to combine the workflow, but can only think of a very complicated solution.

Here's the problem:
I've set up Grunticon so that it only converts my svg files in the build task, to the dist folder. However, I want to also use my svg files in the 'app' or 'dev' environment.

I can think of only one way: 
- Making a separate workflow for Grunticon, and manually put it in my app folder and just copy it in my build task.

Anyone got a slick grunticon workflow ?

Answer (score 0):

my workflow for **"yo-webapp + grunticon"** looks like this:

```
grunt serve
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
svgmin: {
  dist: {
    ...
  },
  server: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images/svgs',
      src: '{,*/}*.svg',
      dest: '<%= config.app %>/images/svg-src'
    }]
  }
},

grunticon: {
  dist: {
    ...  
  },
  server: {
      files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images/svg-src',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= config.app %>/images/svg-dist'
       }],

  }
},
```

in `grunt.registerTask('serve',....` you have to add `grunticon:server`:

```
grunt.task.run([
'clean:server',
'wiredep',
'concurrent:server',
'autoprefixer',
'grunticon:server',
'connect:livereload',
'watch'
]);
```

optional you can add "grunticon" to the "watch" task like this:

```
  grunticon: {
    files: ['<%= config.app %>/images/svgs/*.svg'],
    tasks: ['svgmin:server', 'grunticon:server']
  },
```